# angularjs fullscreen homepage only

Tags: angularjs, fullscreen

I am working on a website that has a fullscreen background only on the homepage. On other pages, they use normal bootstrap container. I used an additional view in order to pass the 100% height to its inner css. But this way, all other pages are forced to moved down, because the space above them are the 100% height. My question is how I do remove the 'style = height:100%' if I am not at homepage?

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="enterHome" style="height:100%;"></div> <!-- additional view -->

    <div ui-view="navbar"></div>
    <div ui-view="body"></div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>    
</body>
```

my app.js is like below: (ie, for state = enterHome, I only have the enterHome template displayed.)

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
$stateProvider
    .state('enterHome',{
        url:"/",            
        views:{
            "navbar":{
            },
            "carousel":{
            },
            "enterHome":{
                templateUrl:"templates/enterHome.body.html",
                controller: "EnterHomeBodyController"
            },
            "footer":{                  
            }               
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test that the current state is the homepage state:

```
<div ui-view="enterHome" style="{{ ('homepage' | isState) ? 'height:100%;' : '' }}></div>
```

Or, to be cleaner, define a `full-height` css class with `height: 100%`, and apply the class if the state is homepage:

```
<div ui-view="enterHome" ng-class="{ 'full-height' : ('homepage' | isState) }></div>
```

Comment: The strange thing is that when i use

    <div ui-view="enterHome" class="fullHeight"></div>

it works. But if use below, it doesn't work....

    <div ui-view="enterHome" ng-class="{ 'full-height' : ('enterHome' | isState) }"></div>

the state in my app.js is as below:

    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
 $stateProvider
  .state('enterHome',{
   url:"/",   
   views:{
    "navbar":{
     
    },
    "enterHome":{     templateUrl:"templates/enterHome.body.html",
     controller: "EnterHomeBodyController"

    },
    ...

Comment: Brilliant, JB Nizet. It actually works very well. I had a different css name. When I changed the full-height css name, it works!!! Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS like

```
.full-height {
    height:100%;
}
```

Than you can use ng-class in your template

```
<div ui-view="enterHome" ng-class="full-height: isHomePage"></div>
```

And in your homepage controller:

```
$scope.isHomePage = true;
```

In other pages variable won't be defined, so it will be `false` and full-height class won't be applied.

Comment: thanks for reply. JB Nizet's solution already works. But I have a question to your reply. I tried a similar method as well, but I couldn't get my head arround for your method. In order to return $scope.isHomePage = true, I have to have the controller defined outside <div ui-view="enterHome" ...   In other words, the controller has to include the <div ui-view=....    That means I have to declear my controller in a place like the body tag? But how do I define the body of the controller (do I made a new a state in app.js)?

Comment: actually you have several options: 1) you can use ng-init and define variable there and redefine in other controllers (looks like quite dirty hack) 2) use ng-init and define variable false there and redefine it only on homepage controller 3) you can use ng-class on root of your homepage template - looks better for me 4) use isState filter, which you already use